# Rounding hour numbers doing daylight saving time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone show how I do something as simple as round to the nearest integer?

```
select round((24+24+24)/24,0)    result: 3
select round((24+24+23)/24,0)    result: 2
select round((24+24+25)/24,0)    result: 3
```

Is there something I can do so all three examples will give me the result 3?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of database is this?

Comment: Hi Joel 
it's Microsoft.

Comment: @Blab MS produce multiple database engines.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is integer division. All of the values are integers, so the 2.9whatever is truncated to just 2 before you even start rounding.

This works just fine by including a floating point value with the division operation:

```
select round((24+24+24)/24.0,0)
select round((24+24+23)/24.0,0)
select round((24+24+25)/24.0,0)
```

The other option is always just throw in a bonus hour. Then you don't even need to round:

```
select (24+24+24+1)/24
select (24+24+23+1)/24
select (24+24+25+1)/24
```

Comment: I see now, I need to cast the hours as decimal, and then it'll work for me.
thank you Joel.
I see your latest edit with the 24.0. That's clever, thanks.